# Google Cloud Datastore Emulator refusing HTTP-based reset requests halfway through test suite

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, python-unittest, google-app-engine-python

I'm working on migrating a Python 2 App Engine app from NDB to Cloud NDB as a precursor to migrating to Python 3. Per recommendations elsewhere, I've been replacing my usage of Testbed with the local Datastore Emulator, and for the most part that's been working out. What I'm running into is an error that starts popping up about halfway through the 580 unit tests in our test suite. The error message would seem to suggest that the emulator isn't capable of keeping up with the rapidfire reset requests coming from the test setUp() method.

All of my tests derive from a base class with the following setUp() method:

```
NDB_CLIENT = ndb.Client(project='myproject')
NDB_CLIENT.host = 'localhost:8089'
NDB_CLIENT.secure = False

class MyTestCase(unittest.TestCase):
 def setUp(self):
 self.testapp = webapp2.WSGIApplication([])
 # clear datastore
 requests.post('http://localhost:8089/reset')
 self.ndb_context = NDB_CLIENT.context()
 self.ndb_context.__enter__()
```

I'm running the Cloud Datastore in a terminal window with the following command:

```
$ gcloud beta emulators datastore start --no-store-on-disk --consistency=1.0 --host-port=localhost:8089
```

About halfway through the test suite, the tests begin failing with this error:

```
ERROR: test_a_thing (my_test.Test)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test/my_test.py", line 11, in setUp
  File "/Users/myuser/Projects/MyProject/test/_base_test.py", line 29, in setUp
  File "/Users/myuser/Projects/MyProject/lib/requests/api.py", line 119, in post
  File "/Users/myuser/Projects/MyProject/lib/requests/api.py", line 61, in request
  File "/Users/myuser/Projects/MyProject/lib/requests/sessions.py", line 530, in request
  File "/Users/myuser/Projects/MyProject/lib/requests/sessions.py", line 643, in send
  File "/Users/myuser/Projects/MyProject/lib/requests/adapters.py", line 516, in send
ConnectionError: HTTPConnectionPool(host='localhost', port=8089): Max retries exceeded with url: /reset (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x113715610>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 8] nodename nor servname provided, or not known',))
```

If I run any of these test files by themselves, they all pass. I've investigated and even removed the test files running roughly when the errors begin but that hasn't helped either. I'm not aware of any other way to reset the datastore between tests and the datastore emulator output in the terminal doesn't indicate there's a problem at all, so I'm at a loss on how to troubleshoot the issue.

Comment: Are you sure that you’re properly closing all connections in the tests? Sounds a bit like a socket exhaustion issue.

Comment: From the error message it looks like you are creating a new pool for every request instead of reusing the pool for a single host:port pair.  Either way, without the code from adapters.py or any interesting transforms in between it's difficult to help.

Comment: My [sessions.py](https://github.com/psf/requests/blob/master/requests/sessions.py) and [adapters.py](https://github.com/psf/requests/blob/master/requests/adapters.py) are unmodified from what's on Github. I'll take a look at the pool exhaustion angle.